# Is the target predicate of the induction in the proof of the Steinitz replacement theorem in wikipedia problematic?

Tags: linear-algebra, logic

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma), the Stenitz replacement therorem is stated and proved as follows:

[image]

I think the predicate in the beginning that he want to prove is not exactly what should be. To see this, I rewrite this theorem, more logically:

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$. Let $S,I\subseteq V$. Then
$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\forall m\in\mathbb{N},\left(\begin{cases}S\text{ spans }V\\I\text{ is linearly independent}\\|S|=n\wedge |I|=m\end{cases}\Longrightarrow \begin{cases}m\leq n\\
\exists S'\subseteq S,|S|'=n-m\wedge S\cup S'\text{ spans }V\end{cases}\right)$

To prove this sentence by mathematical induction. We may go as follows: first let $n$ be any natural numbers, then prove $\forall m\in\mathbb{N},\left(\begin{cases}S\text{ spans }V\\I\text{ is linearly independent}\\|S|=n\wedge |I|=m\end{cases}\Longrightarrow \begin{cases}m\leq n\\
\exists S'\subseteq S,|S|'=n-m\wedge S\cup S'\text{ spans }V\end{cases}\right)$.

To prove this quantified sentence, make the induction on $m$. Notice that the predicate (of $m$) here to be proved is $\begin{cases}S\text{ spans }V\\I\text{ is linearly independent}\\|S|=n\wedge |I|=m\end{cases}\Longrightarrow \begin{cases}m\leq n\\
\exists S'\subseteq S,|S|'=n-m\wedge S\cup S'\text{ spans }V\end{cases}$. Then we need to show that

(i) Check when $m=0$, $P(m)$ is true.

(ii) Suppose $P(k)$ is true, check then $P(k+1)$ is true.

The sentence said in the wikipedia is $\forall k\in\{1,\cdots,m\},~k\leq n\wedge ...$, which is weird, and shouldn't it be $\begin{cases}S\text{ spans }V\\I\text{ is linearly independent}\\|S|=n\wedge |I|=m\end{cases}\Longrightarrow \begin{cases}m\leq n\\
\exists S'\subseteq S,|S|'=n-m\wedge S\cup S'\text{ spans }V\end{cases}$?

Even if we agree that the target predicate is as the author said, then why did the author continue to make an induction on "$k$"? Shouldn't he make an induction on $m$...?

Comment: Proofs in wikipedia articles are frequently not very good and this one is a case in point. Here you definitely want to do induction on $m$ (and you'll get a stronger inductive hypothesis if you switch $\forall n\forall m \ldots$ to $\forall m\forall n\ldots$). I suggest you take this up on wikipedia using the Talk or Edit tabs. If you want some help on MSE first, why don't you update your question to give your proposed proof and ask for comments on it.

Comment: @RobArthan My proof is the same as Friedberg's, and since this is a popular book in linear algebra(I don't personally like it, though), it is reasonable for me to think that when it comes to proof of this Replacement Theorem using induction, most of people know and use this proof. (Moreover I suggest the beginning of the proof, so I think people here know it.)

Comment: Anyway, will there be a chance that this proof in the wikipedia is valid, though it is written bad? Moreover, how can we transfer a proof to $\forall m\forall n\ldots$ (do you mean we make an induction on $n$)?

Comment: the wikipedia proof needs fixing. My point about swapping the quantifiers is that it gives you a stronger inductive hypothesis (you prove by induction on $m$ that for all $n$ ...). If you are confident that you have a better proof for the wikipedia page, please take the discussion to wikipedia. If you want help with the details of your proposed replacement for the wikipedia proof, please post the proof here and ask for comments.